# Eloquent query to blade on view styled better?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm doing an assignment (never ending assignments).
I have a query in my controller that sums up certain table items by month and then I show them in a view.
However, I feel I could have done this in a better way as the output looks not great and I'm not sure how to style it.

**Controller method**

```
  public function monthly()
{ 
    $activity = DB::table('activities')
    ->select(
        DB::raw("Month(date) as Month"),
        DB::raw("SUM(minutes) as total_minutes"),
        DB::raw("SUM(distance) as total_distance"))
    ->orderBy("month")
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("month"))
    ->get();
    return view ('summary/monthly',compact('activity')); }
```

*** View ***

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
{{$activity}}

@endsection
```

**Output in view**

[image: what is displayed on the view]

Any tips on what I could do better?

**Edit**
Oh man I was definitely over thinking my approach and thought it was an error with my controller. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap4 by any change? If so, have a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
@foreach($activity as $singleActivity)
   {{$singleActivity->Month}} 
   {{$singleActivity->total_minutes}} 
   {{$singleActivity->total_distance}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the loop on your blade file.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

     @section('content')
     @foreach($activity as $acti )
          <div class="activity">
              <div class="month">{{ $acti->Month }}
              </div>
              <div class="minutes">{{ $acti->total_minutes }}
              </div>
              <div class="distance">{{ $acti->total_distance }}
              </div>
          </div>         
     @endforeach

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your data using @forelse and displa it with table

```
@forelse ($activity as $act)
    <li>
       Month: {{ $act->Month }} Total Minutes: {{ $act->total_minutes}} Total Distance: {{ $act->total_distance}}
    </li>

@empty
    <p>No Activities</p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you like, but how is it?

```
<table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>TotalMinutes</th>
      <th>TotalDistance</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     @foreach($activity as $act)
      {{$act->Month}} 
      {{$act->total_minutes}} 
      {{$act->total_distance}}
     @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```